# .dockerignore being ignored by docker compose

Tags: testdriven.io

I have the following docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build: ./project
    command: uvicorn app.main:app --reload --workers 1 --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
    volumes:
      - ./project:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 8002:8000
    environment:
      - ENVIRONMENT=dev
      - TESTING=0
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@web-db:5432/web_dev # new
      - DATABASE_TEST_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@web-db:5432/web_test # new
    depends_on: # new
      - web-db
```

Within ./project there is a .dockerignore that is used to ignore files within ./project. However these files are not being ignored. Does the volume take precedent and ignores .dockerignore? ./project:/usr/src/app.

How can I prevent files within ./project from being mounted onto the image?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`.dockerignore` does not work like that: it is mean for your build process, so that it does not consider certain files as the [build context](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) of your image, and are not used in your `Dockerfile`. Volumes will always include *all* files in the directory, hidden ones too.